# Which flow algorithm on a graph is used when the capacity is a rational number?

Tags: ford-fulkerson

Does ford fulkerson only use whole numbers? I tried to understand this but without success

Thank you

Comment: There are [many network flow algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions). You may want to clarify whether algorithms other than Ford-Fulkerson algorithm are covered.

Answer (score 1):

Since all steps of the algorithm merely involve addition, you can compute the least common multiple $m$ of the denominators of all weights involved, and creating $G'$ from $G$ by multiplying all weights by $m$.

Then all weights are integers and you can run Ford-Fulkerson. You can divide the results from it by $m$ again to get back your rationals.